# Why can't I see all JS object properties on a Mongoose document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm writing a route in Express (Node.js) in which i pull some data from mongoose. Let's say that at some some point I need to compare if employee._id is in array of bad employees id::

```
let employees = await EmployeeModel.find().exec();
employees.forEach(function (employee) {
    if (arrayOfBadEmployees.indexOf(employee._id) !== -1) {
        employee.isBad = true;
    }
});
console.log(employees);
console.log(employees[0].isBad);
```

and here's my output:

```
[ { __v: 0, name: 'Employee X', _id: 1 },
  { __v: 0, name: 'Employee Y', _id: 3 },
  { __v: 0, name: 'Employee Z', _id: 5 } ]
true
```

So when I can't see 'isBad' property when I console.log the whole array/object, but this property is still there? When i check with propertyIsEnumerable('isBad') it says true.

Comment: What do you see when you call `console.log(JSON.stringify(•))` instead of just `console.log(•)`?

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin, the outcome is [{"_id":1,"name":"Employee X","__v":0},{"_id":3,"name":"Employee Y","__v":0},{"_id":5,"name":"Employee Z","__v":0}]

Comment: Maybe `isBad: true` isn't added in the `forEach` check but is already in the prototype of the employee object? I don't have enough experience with Mongoose to say *why* the property would be there, but it would explain why `employees[0].isBad === true` and it wouldn't show when stringifying the object. You can test this by logging `console.log(employees[0].__proto__)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongoose, by default, returns an instance of [`MongooseDocument`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js), which doesn't expose your data directly and adds convenience methods like `populate` or `save`

You can use the [`lean`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) option to get raw objects instead.

`MongooseDocument` also exposes a [`toObject`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) function if you need to get editable documents.